# XML-based RESTful API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a basic RESTful service with `rails g scaffold` and it fails to accept XML request sent by ActiveResource (works fine with JSON POST requests and XML GET requests). It fails with `ActionController::ParameterMissing` so obviously it has something to do with whitelisting but I can't figure out what exactly I should send. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that XML support was removed in Rails 4 so `actionpack-xml_parser` gem is required to deal with XML requests.

Answer (score 1):

Add to `Gemfile`

```
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
```

execute `bundle install` and configure the rack middleware by adding the following line to `config/application.rb`.

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::XmlParamsParser
```

As per instruction from [sikachu/actionpack-xml_parser](https://github.com/sikachu/actionpack-xml_parser)

nJoy!