# Rails API Create Action accept JSON OR XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I would like to my create action on my rails API to accept either a JSON POST or and XML POST.  Do I need to do anything special or should it just work out of the box as long as every comes through as params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails just sees them as params that are passed in.  However you will want to have a respond to block that responds properly to xml vs json

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml { #render XML STUFF }
  format.json { #render JSON STUFF }
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, Rails 4 removed support for XML. You may need to install the `actionpack-xml_parser` gem to support receiving XML as POST params. This requires you to add the following to `config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::XmlParamsParser
```

This was answered originally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143001/xml-based-restful-api/37623922?noredirect=1#comment62736840_37623922).

Don't forget to restart your Rails server once you're done :)